# android adding a second tab bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am developing an android application that contains tabs. my application is like this:

[image]

Please notice that I have an action bar that contains many tabs.

Now I want to add an extra tab bar. what i mean is: in the `players` activity i want to have anotion action bar. for example `players under 21 years` and `players above 21 years`

how can i do that please?

#### what i have  tried

i tried manking many bottons with view pager. and when the user press on any button, i slide the view pager. it works good. but i would like to know if there is a standard solution.

#### hint

i think that action bar at the top and ation bar at the botton will help. but i don't know if this is available.

thank u very mush.

Answer (score 0):

The framework provides `TabHost`, which you can bind to the `ViewPager` from by setting an `OnTabChangedListener` and changing the current page based on the selection. It's slightly more complicated than just using buttons, but you get the tab theme

Comment: I already implement ontabchanged. what you see now is four fragments. i am asking how to add a second tab bar on the current fragment

Comment: @user3110137: Yes, I was talking about implementing a [`TabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) and it's `setOnTabChangedListener()` method.

Comment: kindly show me a screen have the tab host with an acction bar

Comment: @user3110137: Sorry, I don't have such a screenshot at hand. There are probably some `TabHost` samples in the Api Demos if you want to check them out.